# jquery how to parse json in load event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a little problem. I am opening jQuery dialog with fallowing code:

```
$('#dialog').html('<img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" width="100" height="100" />');
$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    modal: true,
    position: ['center', 'center'],
    title: _title,
    autoResize:true,
    width: 'auto',
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
    }).load(url, function(data) {
        var arr=$.parseJSON(data);
        console.log('Rez' + arr['result']);
        console.log('result_msg' + arr['result_msg']);
        $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
            if ($.type(value) === 'object')
            {
                console.log('rid: '+ value['rid']);
                console.log('rnos: '+ value['rnos']);
            }
        });
        $(this).dialog("option", "position", ['center', 'center'] );
    });
```

All works great if i am fetching html. But if i fetch json, then how i can format it and display to user inside #dialog div?

If i use ajax call after #dialog is open, #dialog contents won't change. Is there a way to add custom success callback to `load` event?

If i first load all content and then open dialog, it wont position at screen center.

if i run this code:

```
$('#dialog').html('<img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" width="100" height="100" />');
$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    modal: true,
    position: ['center', 'center'],
    title: _title,
    autoResize:true,
    width: 'auto',
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
    });
    $.ajax({
        dataType : 'json',
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function(server_response){
            console.log(server_response);
            $('#dialog').html('vv'); // <---- even this doesn't shows
            switch(server_response.result)
            {
                case 'choose':
                    var linki = '';
                    $.each(server_response, function (index, value) {
                        if ($.type(value) === 'object')
                        {
                            linki += '<a href="javascript:;">'+ value['rnos'] +'</a>';
                            //console.log('rid: '+ value['rid']);
                            //console.log('rnos: '+ value['rnos']);
                        }
                    });
                    console.log('Loading HTML: ' + linki);
                    $('#dialog').html(linki);
                break;
                default: $('#dialog').html(server_response.result_msg);
            }
            $('#dialog').dialog("option", "position", ['center', 'center'] );
        }
    });
```

then #dialog content wont change.

**=== Edit ===**

Here is modified `load` event that accomplish what i need, but i am not sure if it is good way.

```
$('#dialog').dialog({...}).load(url, function(data) {
            var arr=$.parseJSON(data);
            $(this).html('<img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" width="100" height="100" />');
            console.log('Rez' + arr['result']);
            console.log('result_msg' + arr['result_msg']);

            switch(arr.result)
            {
                case 'choose':
                    var linki = '';
                    $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
                        if ($.type(value) === 'object')
                        {
                            linki += '<a href="javascript:;">'+ value['rnos'] +'</a><br />';
                            //console.log('rid: '+ value['rid']);
                            //console.log('rnos: '+ value['rnos']);
                        }
                    });
                    console.log('Ielādējam HTML: ' + linki);
                    $(this).html(linki);
                break;
                default: $(this).html(arr.result_msg);
            }



            $(this).dialog("option", "position", ['center', 'center'] );

        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only use `.load()` if the AJAX server returns HTML. If it returns something else and you need to process the data first, you should use `$.get()`. The callback function should do whatever it needs to do to turn the data into HTML, then do:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    // options 
}).html(result);
```

Comment: in this case user wont see loading image (or any progress that content is loading). in this case i need to somewhere else show to user, that content is loading.

Comment: You can do that before you call `$.get()`. `$.load()` is just a shortcut that uses `$.get()` and then calls `$(element).html(data)` when it returns.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with ajax function ?

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : youURL,
    cache : false,
    dataType : 'json',
    data : yourDATA
}).done(function(msg)
{
//ok
}).fail(function()
{
//nok
});
```

With specifying dataType to json, you don't need to parseJSON on msg variable